# reporting vs analysis with Star schema data warehouse

Tags: relational-database, olap, pentaho, cube, star-schema

I'm working on a BI project where i'll use pentaho.

My DW will be modelize as a star schema.
I know that for the analysis part we need to go from this star schema (relational DW) and design the cube thks to schema workbench for example. Thks to that, the analysis tool can do the multidimensional request

For the reporting part, does It also need to know about the cube, or can I just do normal request on the star schema relational DW?

Is it a good or bad thing?

thks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Cubes are for OLAP, which is interactive analysis with Pivot Tables

Your reporting tool, assuming it's not OLAP, should just talk directly to the data warehouse.